# How to make criteria with complex query in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I have query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM activity
WHERE (((userId = 1 OR userId IN(SELECT userId FROM follower WHERE followerId = 1))
AND activityType IN(1, 2, 3))
OR (targetId = 24 AND aType IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I have try to use `model()->findAllBySql($sql)` and it works. But I want to make it using `CDbCriteria`, if you have another solutions let me know it :D

Comment: A bit old question but I need to comment. When dealing with complex queries **DO NOT** use any ORM. You have to deal with pure SQL (AR provides a `findAllBySql()` method).

Comment: @Andrzej Ośmiałowski could you give us the reason why we should use findAllBySql instead of using ORM(Criteria).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could still build this statement with a CDbCriteria I think... something like:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = '
  (
    (
      userId = 1 OR 
      userId IN (SELECT userId FROM follower WHERE followerId = 1)
    )
    AND activityType IN(1, 2, 3)
  )
  OR (
    targetId = 24 
    AND aType IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  )
';
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';
$results=Activity::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

As this point you might as well just write a regular SQL statement, but there might be some benefits to doing it this way: binding params, merging criteria, adding additional criteria, etc.

Answer (score 6):

As long as your plain SQL works, you're safe. There are many times when I have to throw Active Record away and just get the job done in the ol' saner way.

I tried to translate this query into a readable CDbCriteria construction. Bad idea. Yii sucks when it comes to query complex data.

Comment: Thank you @pestaa, I hope Yii will give a solution for complex query :D

Comment: @aslingga It is fundamentally "misdesigned". I'm not saying I can do better, though.

Comment: a bit  later, but 5 years later, what framework would you recommend then?

Comment: @A.Shulzhenko Within the realms of PHP, there is zero point in using anything other than Doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#executing-sql-statements

In your case:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM activity';
$sql .= 'WHERE (((userId = 1 OR userId IN(SELECT userId FROM follower WHERE followerId = 1))';
$sql .= 'AND activityType IN(1, 2, 3))';
$sql .= 'OR (targetId = 24 AND aType IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))';
$sql .= 'ORDER BY id DESC';

$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$results = $command->queryAll();
```

@pestaa is right that sometimes you have to throw active record out the window. This is especially true if you're doing mass updates where looping through numerous models is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you @philip for your solution but now I want to use the CDbCriteria in my Active Record. I have try to use the sql and execute using Activity::model()->findAllBySql($sql) and I think it will give the same result as using SQL Comamnd. :D

Comment: @aslingga, is your question about using CDbCriteria and how to form such a statement? If so, let me know and maybe I can help. One of the advantages of CDbCriteria is it incorporates bound parameters, which is essential in preventing SQL injection if you're querying with user input. I haven't tried your statement above, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I want to combine it with CPanigation in Yii, is there any way to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSqlDataProvider 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

Disclaimer: I know it's not precise answer to this particural question but it might help work around the problem that was given. I suspect the main purpose of this question is getting way to use CGridView, CListView etc. with arbitrary SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I use `CDbCriteria` for complex queries in which I use the `with` feature.

You can build complex criteria like this:

```
$dbCriteria->with=array(
   '<relation1>'=>array( 'condition'=>'<condition for given relation>',
        'with'=>array('<relation2:relation of relation1>'
            =>array(<conditions for relation2>)
        )
        'scopes'=><scopes for relation1>
    )
);
```

I have not checked how `OR` can get into play here.

By using scopes, you can also insert some more complex criteria and still keep your search condition readable.

This is pretty powerful. I didn't see a complete 'tutorial' about this yet; I kind of concluded this from the source code.

Comment: can you add an example? i can't understand how to clone this in real life